# ¿Problema tipo de dato en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda e inquietud bastante grande.
Estaba haciendo una operación en java y estaba esperando un resultado positivo, debido a que todos los números eran positivos.
Pero el resultado me devolvió un número negativo.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=346315*591113+491539;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Y el resultado a esto fue -1446640074.
Alguien por favor que me explique que esta pasando aquí.
Lo hice con la calculadora, con python, con javascript y con todas las anteriores me sirvió. Pero con Java no.

Comment: En la operación `346315*591113` se produce un número entero mayor que el permitido por Java y en ese caso el resultado es un número negativo. Eso se conoce como *integer overflow*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El tipo de dato `int` en java es un entero de 32 bits complemento a dos. Su valor mínimo es -2,147,483,648 y el máximo 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). Tu respuesta  sobre pasa ese limite.  te recomiendo usar `long`, y tu función puede ser `x=(n1*n2)+n3`

```
class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long m= 346315;
    long n = 591113;
    long sum = 491539;
    long res= (m*n)+sum;
    System.out.println(res);
} 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
Pero hice lo que me dijiste y aún sigue dando negativo.

Comment: bueno es porque yo sugerí algo así.  
  class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long m= 346315;
        long n = 591113;
        long sum = 491539;
        long res= (m*n)+sum;
        System.out.println(res);
    } }

Comment: @SuquiNakamoto es que probablemente solo estas poniendo el resultado como long y no los operandos. Tienes que poner `long x=346315L*591113L+491539L;` para que funcione

Comment: Gracias a los dos. Si, era eso, que torpe.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que en la operación long x=346315*591113+491539 primero la JVM lo opera como int y luego lo convierte en long y por eso es necesario agregar la "L" para espesificar que el numero es un long no int, long x=346315L*591113L+491539L